# Amazon AutoBalancer including as first instance one already running

Tags: amazon-ec2, scaling

I've a webserver instance with an Elastic IP in Amazon. That's my main instance.

Now, I'm configuring the loadbalancer and autoscaling. When I create the group, I put min-size 1. So when I launch the autoscaling commands, it appears another instance. So I have the old main instance, and the one created by the autoscaling.

Is it possible to create a group with min-size=0 and have my main instance as the first of that group ?  so I don't have to pay 2 instances when load is low.

In that case ... if one day I want to change the group/triggers configuration, this main instance will be deleted ? :(

Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

No, because your main instance should be your template image that the auto-scaler runs up. You should be able to throw that main instance away and that same template runs up again automatically.

If there's something custom in that main instance, you're working against the design of load balancing and auto scaling.

Comment: I don't have nothing custom in the "main instance", just the IP assigned since I need it for some services. So, for some minutes i won't have webserver instance running :P   so, after that, I can assign the elastic IP to that first instance created by the autoscaling system, right ?

Comment: It doesn't make much sense to have a load balancer and auto scaler then map an IP to only one of the instances. Surely, all the instances (should there be more than one) offer the same web server. You should map a CNAME DNS record from your domain to the public DNS name of the load balancer. That should be what's used externally.

Comment: I need the IP assigned to one of them since I need it for some external services. They need a static IP.  But, what I said makes sense ? I mean, with min-size=1 i will have always one webserver running, right?

Comment: As soon as you put instances under the control of a load balancer, you cannot be assured that the load balancer won't declare an instance failed, terminate it, then start a new one, to which the IP won't be mapped. If you have services that aren't load balanced, they shouldn't be running on an auto-scaled instance, really.